# Shell script fails for every 24 hours with error /bin/mkdir: Argument list too long

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a shell script which needs to run in the background all day 24*7, but it fails for every 24 hours with **error: /bin/mkdir: Argument list too long**.
As a workaround, I will re-run the script in the background and it runs for 24 hours and then again it fails with the same error.

> When i say it runs for 24 hours means, this script gets triggered for every 30 mins and it completes successfully, this continues for a 24 hour period, then it fails and then it will not run. Here i have to manually restart the script, then it runs for 24 hours and fails.>

*For the successful and failure run, the dir_path values are same.*

To fix this issue I modified my code to create mkdir command as:

```
echo ${dir_path} | xargs mkdir -p >> ${log_path}/${log_file} 2>&1
```

but no luck.

Any inputs or idea will be helpful.

Comment: So what is dir_path when it crashes?

Comment: What is in `${dir_path}` when it fails?  Normally, `xargs` would ensure that the argument list is not too long.  Do you accumulate some excessively long environment variable values?  The 'argument list too long' error occurs when the combined length of environment and arguments is too long.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  It will be like **:/x/abcde/aabcdefghih/klm/nop_qr_st/uvw_xyz_abcdef_ghi/klmn_op_qrst/final_dir_path**

Comment: Any spaces in directory or file names? Did you consider writing a C program, with [nftw(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) and relevant [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).... Did you use [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand what is happening?

Comment: Also, please show some [mre] equivalent to your shell script. Without real code, you won't get help here. Ask permission to show your code here, then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66173739/edit) your question a lot. Add several paragraphs of details

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch no spaces in directoy path

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add clarification or requested information. What's the difference between `dir_path` values when it works and when it fails? Maybe add a line `echo ${dir_path} >> ${log_path}/${log_file}` to see the value if it's not already part of an error message.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : But it doesn't not fail for every run. If it fails then for sure will change the lengthy directory path.  In 24 hours time period all are successfull runs and the job goes well. Suppose if the job fails now , i will manually restart it and then it runs for  24 hours from now and fails with that error.

Comment: @Bodo : Values for dir_path are same for successful and failure run.

Comment: It isn't clear how the script containing the failing `mkdir` is used.  There are implications that it runs continuously, and also that it is run periodically by something (`cron` perhaps).  However, there is no chance for anyone here to reproduce your problem.  You will have to track it yourself.  I would make sure that I log the environment and the command execution in timestamped log files. I'd then study these logs, noting the differences between when the command succeeds and when it fails.  Something will probably leap out at you when you do it correctly.  (Use `xargs -t mkdir -p …` too.)

Comment: @SathishKumarChidambaram **Please [edit] your question** to add requested information. **Don't use comments to answer.** If the problem is not caused by different `dir_path` values, then we need to see more code.

Comment: If the value of `${dir_path}` is the same when it succeeds and when it fails, then something else in the environment has changed.  _You_ must find out what that is because we _cannot_ (because we don't have your code or access to your machine).  On macOS, when I use `perl -le 'print "AbcdEfgh" x (8 * 16 * 255)' | xargs -t echo`, I get the message `xargs: insufficient space for argument` until I reduce 255 to 252 (I have just over 2 KiB of environment variables).  That's different from the message you're seeing.

Comment: I think that some rough idea about what else the script does would be useful. Probably it is a forever loop which sleeps for 30 minutes, then does something and then restarts. I don't think your script is covered by industrial secrets... post at least the relevant parts.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to get that error when you are using xargs. It should protect you against this error if it can. However, if you fill up your entire environment with data, there is no space left for even a single mkdir call. It's all full, and the system has no other option than giving you an error.

Exported variables count towards your argument list size.

I think what is happening is that you are using "export var=something" to put data in your environment. This data is growing over time. Maybe it's an array?

You can use this to debug your sizes:

```
echo | xargs --show-limits
```

It's just a guess. I can't know for sure if you are not sharing all your code.

Comment: Thanks @veda for suggestion, i too was thinking about that , but we are trying to read the environment and fix it.